# Take a trac repository dump

Tags: trac, dump

I have a trac repository available on a local network and need to take a dump of the trac data to be able to access it out of that network.
Can anyone suggest a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a unified command to dump both the trac project and a possible attached svn repo, but for separate dumping, Trac has a `hotcopy` command and svn a `dump` command.

[Trac Backup - The Trac project](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracBackup)

[svn dump manual](http://www.informatik.fh-mannheim.de/subversion11/re31.html)

Answer (score 0):

Good set of answers on serverfault for this topic - https://serverfault.com/questions/6147/how-do-i-backup-my-trac-instalations